# Core Data: NSFetchRequest returning no error, but zero values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am refactoring my existing core data manager to use an `NSPersistentContainer`. I have what seems to be some relatively straightforward code to fetch my entities:

```
class CoreDataManager {
    
    static let shared: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DateAid")
        
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        
        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return container
    }()
    
    static func fetch<T: NSManagedObject>() throws -> [T] {
        let context = shared.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))

        do {
            return try context.fetch(request) as [T]
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

However, in another class where I call this code, it retrieves nothing. I am calling it like so:

```
do {
    let events: [Event] = try CoreDataManager.fetch()
} catch {
    throw error
}
```

It's not erroring out, but it's not retrieving anything. Hence, I can't get any idea what's going wrong. Things to note:

- My xcdatamodel is correctly named "DateAid"
- Breakpoints are hitting in the container's `loadPersistentStores` and I can print to the console a proper `storeDescription` that shows the path to the sqlite file
- `String(describing: T.self)` works fine, as it returns "Event" (I've tried hard-coding the string "Event" as well to no avail)
- the `persistentContainer`'s properties all seem to be set.
- I know the entities are all still there because when I go back to my existing implementation (with all the manual core data setup in the app delegate), it properly fetches the entities.

What could the issue be? Is there a chance it could be some kind of sync/async race condition issue happening outside of my example? Am I missing something obvious? Any help or direction to either solve or figure out how to debug the problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might help to enable Core Data debugging (compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/12306343/1187415).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: "I know the entities are all still there because when I go back to my existing implementation (with all the manual core data setup in the app delegate), it properly fetches the entities." Could you give us that code? Also, knowing that `loadPersistentStores` seems to be async, could you check that there its completion is called before you fetch? Or is there any message in console somewhere?

Comment: @Larme: `loadPersistentStores` is *synchronous* unless you set the `shouldAddStoreAsynchronously` flag, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403540/1187415.

Comment: I created a small gist showing what it was previously here: gist.github.com/akwilliamson/ad8518f714798661e9b85947b3575f5f#file-coredata-swift I've since edited my class above in the question to match the store description options and based on the feedback from Stamenkovski below. It's still broken but hopefully getting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`loadPersistentStores` is never called in your implementation.

instead of doing this (which you never call)

```
private var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
     let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DateAid")
     container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
         if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
         }
      }
     return container
}()
```

create singleton instance of your `NSPersistentContainer` like this:

```
static let shared: NSPersistentContainer = {
     let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DateAid")
     container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
         if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
         }
      }
     return container
}()
```

Note:

```
static let shared = CoreDataManager()
```

Should be removed, because it is not doing anything at the moment.

Edit 1:

I just saw that you are loading persistent store each time you make fetch request, you should load the store only once because it is adding unnecessary work each time you perform a fetch request.

Edit 2:

You can make the `CoreDataManager` subclass of `NSPersistentContainer` and you can access the `viewContext` right within the class without `shared.viewContext`

Quote from Apple

> [NSPersistentContainer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack) is intended to be subclassed. Your subclass is a
> convenient place to put Core Data–related code like functions that
> return subsets of data and calls to persist data to disk.

Edit 3 - How to:

1. Subclassing

```
class CoreDataManager: NSPersistentContainer {
    
    private override init(name: String, managedObjectModel model: NSManagedObjectModel) {
        super.init(name: name, managedObjectModel: model)
    }

    public static let shared: CoreDataManager = {
        let container = CoreDataManager(name: "DateAid")
               
        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        try? container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        return container
    }()
    
   public func fetch<T: NSManagedObject>() throws -> [T] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))

        do {
            return try self.viewContext.fetch(request) as [T]
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

2. Fetch request

```swift
do {
    let events: [Event] = try CoreDataManager.shared.fetch()
} catch {
    throw error
}
```

Comment: Good point on the performance issue. I've edited my code to include the changes you described and reflected them in my original question above. It's still not working but I'm hopefully closer to a solution.

Comment: I edited my answer with further explanation, please let me know if you run into trouble.

Comment: The line `return try self.viewContext.fetch(request) as [T]` triggers a runtime crash when calling the fetch with the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unsupported feature in this configuration'"

Comment: If you did some changes to the managed object model please reinstall the app on your phone/simulator