# Core Data background task context seems to occasionally be nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am creating an entity and saving it in the background to core data. Most of the time this works, however, occasionally on a clean install of my app I get a crash but I can't figure out why.

Update: I can only produce this the very first time it's installed on to my device. Subsequent deletes and reinstalls are fine!?

Here's my code:

```
 class CoreDataStack {
  static let managedObject: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    guard let modelUrl = Bundle.module.url(
      forResource: "Model",
      withExtension: "momd"
    ) else {
      return .init()
    }
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelUrl) ?? .init()
  }()

  lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(
      name: "Model",
      managedObjectModel: Self.managedObject
    )
    container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        print("error")
      }
    }
    return container
  }()
}


class Foo: NSManagedObject {
  @nonobjc
  class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Foo> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Foo>(entityName: "Foo")
  }

  @NSManaged var id: String

  init(
    context: NSManagedObjectContext,
    id: String
  ) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(
      forEntityName: "Foo",
      in: context
    )! // <- Crash happens here!
    super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    self.id = id
  }
}

class MyObject {
  func save() {
    let container = coreDataStack.persistentContainer

    container.performBackgroundTask { [weak self] context in
      let foo = Foo(
        context: context,
        id: "someId",
      )

      self?.coreDataStack.saveContext(context)
    }
  }
}
```

The crash happens on this line when creating the entity `Foo`:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(
  forEntityName: "Foo",
  in: context
)!
```

It doesn't like the force unwrapping there. The only way that I can see that happening is if `context` is `nil`. Because Apple state:

> Raises internalInconsistencyException if context is nil.

I get the context automatically from `performBackgroundTask`. Why would that ever be `nil`?

Comment: It is unlikely that the context is nil, since that would throw a different exception as you note. The `entity` function has returned `nil`  and you are force unwrapping.  Note that `loadPersistentStores` is an asynchronous operation. It looks like a race condition where the persistent container is not yet ready and the object model has not been loaded but you try and create a managed object.

Comment: @Paulw11 I thought it might be that but I saw this answer on stack overflow which suggested it's actually loaded synchronously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403540/362840. Also I can't reproduce it, even after deleting and reinstalling - it only occurs the first time on the device. How can I solve that?

Comment: Is the saveContext operation occurring on the context queue?

Comment: @valeCocoa It is but the crash is happening before it even gets to save

Comment: The simple solution is not to force unwrap; make the initialiser failable , but you will need some sort of recovery strategy. Also consider whether you really need to use a background operation in this case. You would normally only use a background operation where you are performing bulk updates.

Comment: Do you retain `CoreDataStack`? Perhaps it goes away at some point?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I'll try that, but I do need bg operations.

Comment: @RobZombie It is retained with a strong ref

Comment: Can you try to access entity description via `Foo.entity`? Otherwise it looks like the context you receive is disconnected from persistent store, you could probably verify that via `moc.persistentStoreCoordinator`, which means the store perhaps hasn't loaded yet...

Comment: @Tometoyou just for the sake of it, could you please also add the saveContext method source code?